# Accessing the Order object from the Cart Id in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am POSTing the Cart id to my module method. From that I can obviously create the Cart object using that id. But how do I access the Order object that corresponds to that Cart object?

I've tried something like;

```
$cart = new Cart($_POST['id']);

var_dump($this->context->order);
```

And also trying to do a sort of where() query on the Order (where id_cart is equal to the id in my Cart object);

```
$order = new Order('id_cart', $cart->id);
```

It is probably really obvious but I just don't know Prestashop very well.

The reason I am trying to do this is so I change the status of an Order if the payment has timed out.

Answer (score 4):

I win;

```
$order = Order::getOrderByCartId((int)($cart->id));
```

Comment: actually, it returned order_id not order obj

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$order = Order::getByCartId($cart->id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am passing `$cart->id` to function in my module and then I pass it to .tpl where I can access it.

But in function in controller I can not get to an order object

Either:

```php
$order = Order::getByCartId($cart->id)
```

or

```php
$order = Order::getOrderByCartId((int)($cart->id));
```

no results.
I have

```php
public function displayMyHooKName($params) {
   
   $id_cart = $params['id_cart'];
/* $id_cart has value of cart id - I have checked */


}
```

I tried:

```php
 $cart = new Cart($params['id_cart']);

$order = Order::getOrderByCartId((int)($cart->id));
/*or*/
$order = Order::getByCartId($cart->id);
```

so how to access `php$order` knowing `$cart->id` ?

---

OK

```php
$order = Order::getOrderByCartId((int)($cart->id));
```

gives back

```php
#order_id
```

so I did:

```php
 $cart = new Cart($params['id_cart']);
 $orderID = Order::getOrderByCartId((int)($cart->id));
 $order = new Order($orderID);

 $products = $order->getProducts();
```

and my

```php
$products
```

is empty

---

SOLVED

OK I got it. Code above is 100% correct and it works as it should.

I was smart enough to try to get data from order object - before order was placed:) Was calling my hook on order-address.tpl.

So products data were in

```php
$cart->getProducts();
```

However maybe my case will help someone.

@Mike Nguyen post should be marked as answer, Mike has a point.